# Java How to make "Static" variable name to be dynamic

Tags: java, static

Suppose I have a Class Child

```
public class child{
  public static int age = 1;
}
```

And I am using class child static variable age in class School

```
public class school{
 int var_age;
  public school(){     //school constructor
   var_age = child.age;
 }
}
```

Value in age of class child could be any of these below depending on some **logic**:

```
public static int age = 1;
public static int age = 2;
```

How could i achieve this where should i apply that **logic**? Also it is **mandatory for class school code to remain same**.

Comment: really get confused: (1) Is it `public static String var1 = "1";`, or `public static int var1 = 1;`? (2) What is `public class(){`? (3) What is `var2`? (You didn't declare `var2` in `class2`) (4) Please follow the naming convention.

Comment: corrected the naming convention

Comment: can you elaborate your logic please, because i'm too stupid to understand `var1 = 1, var1 =2` i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided very little information about what kind of **logic** this would be, but in any case it should be inside the class `Child`. Depending on what kind of **logic** it is I would probably put it inside the constructor.

---

Suppose you have the following:

```
    public class Child(){
       public static int age = 1;

       public Child(){
       }
    }

    public class School(){
       int var_age;

       public School(){
          var_age = Child.age;
       }
    }
```

With this code the variable `var_age` in the class `School` will always be assigned to the same value. That would be **1** in this case. If you want to make it depend on your *logic* you will have to implement it somewher (in class `Child`, since you're not allowed to edit class `School`). There are two obvious ways to do this;

- First way of doing it - The Constructor-way:

  ```
  public class Child(){
     public static int age = 1;

     public Child(){ 
        age = yourLogic(); // Assign age depending on your logic here!
     }
  }
  ```

With this way of doing it, your variable `age` will have a default value, **1**, and as soon as an object of type `Child` is being created, it will take on the value defined by your logic. Judging from your feedback however, what you probably need is the second version.

- The second way of doing it - The field-way:

  ```
  public class Child(){
     public static int age = yourLogic(); // Assign age to logic here!

     public Child(){
     }
  }
  ```

This way, the variable `age` will have the value defined by your logic as a default value, so even if no instance of class `Child` is being created. This is probably what you were looking for. However note: 
Depending on how computationally complicated your logic is, this can be a very bad practice.

---

By the way, **DO NOT** confuse the java static with the antonym of "dynamic". `static` in a java sense merely means that the variable is bound to the *type* instead of the *instance / Object*. That means it can be accessed without having to call or create an instance of the surrounding class. If you want the opposite of dynamic, that would be `final` in java.

Comment: I tried writing logic(could be any) inside constructor of child class, but static is always called before calling child class constructor.

Comment: How do you mean "static is always called first". Do you mean the class `Child` is only getting instantiated _after_ it's variable is being used in class `School`? (Btw. please be more clear in the future, and please, **PLEASE** follow a clear java _Naming convention_ when posting code!)

Comment: yes "class Child is only getting instantiated after it's variable is being used in class School"

Comment: @user3620016 I edited my answer to what I suppose you need in that case.

Comment: Thanks Phil "Solution 2" worked for me, but as you suggested will be changing my code to work with "Solution 1"

Comment: @user3620016 you're welcome. If this helped, it would be appreciated if you could mark the question as answered, by accepting my answer. thanks